# Laravel pagination style is broken

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, tailwind-css, laravel-mix, laravel-pagination

The pagination in my project displays as shown below:

[image]

And renders the following HTML:

```html
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination Navigation" class="flex items-center justify-between">
    <div class="flex justify-between flex-1 sm:hidden">
        <span
            class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default leading-5 rounded-md">
            &laquo; Précédent
        </span>

        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/clients?page=2"
            class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 leading-5 rounded-md hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring ring-gray-300 focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
            Suivant &raquo;
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden sm:flex-1 sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between">
        <div>
            <p class="text-sm text-gray-700 leading-5">
                Showing
                <span class="font-medium">1</span>
                to
                <span class="font-medium">10</span>
                of
                <span class="font-medium">11</span>
                results
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span class="relative z-0 inline-flex shadow-sm rounded-md">

                <span aria-disabled="true" aria-label="&amp;laquo; Précédent">
                    <span
                        class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default rounded-l-md leading-5"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </span>

                <span aria-current="page">
                    <span
                        class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default leading-5">1</span>
                </span>
                <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/clients?page=2"
                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 leading-5 hover:text-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring ring-gray-300 focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150"
                    aria-label="Go to page 2">
                    2
                </a>

                <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/clients?page=2" rel="next"
                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md leading-5 hover:text-gray-400 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring ring-gray-300 focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-500 transition ease-in-out duration-150"
                    aria-label="Suivant &amp;raquo;">
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                            clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Which in an [isolated environment](https://codepen.io/medilies/pen/BamMPrp?editors=1010) from my project results in:

[image]

Last time I seen the pagination in my project is a month ago, after that I:

- Upgraded from **Laravel 8** to **Laravel 9**.
- Upgraded from **Tailwind 2.6^** to **Tailwind 3^**.
- Upgraded **Mix**
- Deleted some of the components that comes by default with **Breeze scafolding** .

---

## Edit

When I export the pagination views to `resources\views` using:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Then run:

```
npm run dev
```

**The pagination is fixed!**

**But** When I delete `resources\views\vendor\pagination` and rerun `npm run dev`, **The pagination is broken again!**

This makes me think that **Mix** is missing the CSS classes used in the pagination element. which wasn't the case before I upgrade.

So how can I fix this? (exporting feels like a patch and not a solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going back to the guide [Upgrading your Tailwind CSS projects from v2 to v3](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide)  I noticed:

> If you weren’t already using the purge option in your project, **it’s crucial that you configure your template paths now or your compiled CSS will be empty**.

I fixed the issue by referencing `"./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php"` in `tailwind.config.js` and running `npm run dev`

```js
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
        "./resources/**/*.js",
        "./resources/**/*.vue",
        "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php",
    ],
// ...
}
```

### Checking my upgrade commit

[image]

Because I blindly followed the "**Laravel with Tailwind 3 docs/posts**" without noticing that they did not consider the **Pagination**.

Comment: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/issues/1218

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/7770